# Dynamically build select statement in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, select, dynamic, clob

I have posted the similar question before but the solution to this question seems like it will be completely different, thus I hope this does not qualify for a repost.

Req:
I have 2 columns in a table named `SETUPS` with the following columns:

`ID INTEGER NOT NULL`
`RPT_SCRIPT CLOB NOT NULL`

`RPT_SCRIPT` has select statements in each record. Below is a statement in the clob column `WHERE ID = 1`:

```
SELECT ID,
 Title,
 Desc,
 Type,
 LVL_CNT,
 TYPE_10 VALUE_10,
 TYPE_9 VALUE_9,
 TYPE_8 VALUE_8,
 TYPE_7 VALUE_7,
 TYPE_6 VALUE_6,
 TYPE_5 VALUE_5,
 TYPE_4 VALUE_4,
 TYPE_3 VALUE_3,
 TYPE_2 VALUE_2,
 TYPE_1 VALUE_1
  FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Currently I am writing these select statements manually for all records.

`SETUPS.ID` is mapped to another master table `META.ID` in order to build the select statement.

The column names with pattern `TYPE_%`, i.e. `TYPE_1`, come from the `META` table; there are total of 20 columns in the table with this pattern but in this example I've used only 10 because `META.LVL_CNT = 10`. Similarly if `META.LVL_CNT = 5` then only select columns `TYPE_1`,`TYPE_2`,`TYPE_3`,`TYPE_4`,`TYPE_5`.

The column aliases, i.e. `VALUE_1`, are values which come from the corresponding column where `META.ID = 1` (as in this example).
ID will always be provided, so it can be used to query table `META`.

***EDIT***
The column aliases which come from `META` table will never have a pattern as I have shown in my example, but with `LVL_CNT`, at runtime we will know the number of columns. I tried to @Asfakul's provided logic and built a dynamic sql using the column names retrieved dynamically but when using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INTO` I realized I don't know how many columns will be retrieved and therefore wouldn't be able to dynamically generate the alias name with this method.

Need an approach to automatically build this select statment using above information.. how can I achieve this? Please provide any examples.

Comment: provide us with the sample data... couple of rows will do.  This is achievable with Dynamic SQL

Comment: I've posted the solution to my own answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015830/oracle-12c-sql-string-build-issue/24016833#24016833)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this as the basis

```
declare
    upper_level number;
    t_sql varchar2(1000);
    l_sql varchar2(1000);
begin
    select lvl_cnt into upper_level from 
    SETUPS S,META S
    where s.id=m.id

    l_sql:='SELECT ID,
     Title,
     Desc,
     Type,'||
     upper_level


    for lvl in 1..upper_level
     loop
         t_sql:=t_sql||'type_'||lvl||','
     end loop;
     l_sql:=l_sql||t_sql
     l_sql:=rtrim(l_sql,',');
     l_sql:=l_sql||' FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
    WHERE ID = 1;';

end
```

Comment: I see what you did there! Impressive. The data will never have a fixed pattern, so unfortunately I cannot hard code the alias..

Comment: What do you mean by fixed pattern? Can u elaborate

Comment: My select statement may seem misleading since the alias seems to have a pattern, i.e. VALUE_1, VALUE_2, etc. But that will not be the case, so I can't hard code "VALUE" and then use LVL to append the number. I have to retrieve the alias name from the META table.

Comment: Perhaps we can use LVL_CNT, since that's the only way to know how many columns we are fetching data from, to somehow create variables are runtime to hold the values? Just a thought..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this approach, if you already know how to build dynamic SQL, then use this concept to build your query:

```
    SELECT 'TYPE_' || LEVEL
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 --10 could be a variable
```